# Generating Subsets of a Multiset in Ascending Order of the Sums of the Elements of the Subset

Tags: co.combinatorics, sumsets

I am trying to come up with an algorithm where you can generate combination from a set in a order such that their sums are in increasing order. This set has to be a multiset i.e. repetition allowed.

For example you have a set S = {1,2,2,3,4,5,5}

So, rather than generating all the combinations based on number of items (say start with 1 and 2 items and finally all 7) I want to figure them out in this order:

{1}, {2}, {2}, {1,2}, {1,2}, {3}, {1,3}, {2,2}, {4}..............{1,2,2,3,4,5,5}

Why this order: Well taking sum of these subsets we can see:

{1}, {2}, {2}, {3}, {3}, {3}, {4}, {4}, {4}..............{22}

Do you know any algorithm which can do it efficiently???

Comment: Seems more like a programming question than a math question.

Comment: Generate all subsets and sort them by the elements sum value.

Comment: That'd be extremely costly operation.

Comment: @Moni: What is costly? You will need to generate all subsets anyway, and sorting will bring just a log() factor to that.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Yes...but want to generate them in the ascending order so that if  for many cases the answer (for which this has to generated) might come in the first quarters of numbers we may not need to generate all other 75% combinations.