# Generating all possible subsets in order of sum

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms, combinatorial-optimization

Given a set of positive integers, I am looking for method to algorithmically generate all possible subsets in order of their sum. Because the the count of possible subsets is exponential ($2^n$), it is not feasible to brute-force them and then sort. Instead, the solution would generate one answer at a time, starting with smallest sum (i.e. an online algorithm).

Here's an example:

$$A=\{1,2,10\}$$

And the expected results:

$$S_1=\{\}$$
$$S_2=\{1\}$$
$$S_3=\{2\}$$
$$S_4=\{1,2\}$$
$$S_5=\{10\}$$
$$S_6=\{1,10\}$$
$$S_7=\{2,10\}$$
$$S_8=\{1,2,10\}$$

This problem seems to be related to the [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) and the [Subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). It is also related to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315352/generating-subsets-of-a-multiset-in-ascending-order-of-the-sums-of-the-elements), to which there are unfortunately no answers. In my specific case the previous subsets are known and the overall time complexity is not the issue, but calculating the answers in the correct order. This is why I hope there is a solution that runs in polynomial time per iteration, but in $O(2^n)$ for all answers.

If someone could confirm whether it is possible or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It should be possible to get space complexity $O(2^{n/4})$ using the data structures suggested by [Schroeppel and Shamir (1981)](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0210033).

Comment: Is $O(n)$ per iteration and $O(n 2^n)$ total acceptable? If so, you can achieve this by using any $O(1)$ insert time heap to store the candidate sets. You start with the empty set on the heap, and then any time you take a set $S$ out, you insert $S \cup \{a\}$ for all $a$ larger than all $s \in S$ back to the heap.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Comparison_of_theoretic_bounds_for_variants

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/89453/752906 this Math Stack Exchange question and answer

Comment: @CommandMaster Thank you, that seems to be exactly my problem and the answer I am looking for! Too bad I did not find this earlier.

Comment: I'm not sure the answer at stackexchange satisfies "polynomial time per iteration".

Comment: Note that it is only necessary to solve the problem for subsets of fixed size, since you can run all sizes in parallel with only $O(\log n)$ extra cost per iteration.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay I have tested the algorithm empirically and it seems to be just over O(n) per iteration on average, although there are outliers. So you are right that it might not be technically polynomial, but it does behave very well in practice.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you the main idea in the following steps:

1. You must put initially the empty set directly without counting (I'm assuming that the set contains only positive numbers)
2. You construct the following mathematical program:
   $$ x_i = \begin{cases}
   1 , & \ \text{if the element} \ i \ \text{of the set} \ A \ \text{is chosen;}\\
   0 , & \ \text{otherwise.}
   \end{cases}$$

$$ (P) \begin{cases}
\min \sum_{i=1}^{n} A_i x_i \\
\text{s.t.} \\
\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \geq 1
\end{cases}$$
where $n=|A|$.

3. You solve the problem $(P)$, and let $B$ the set of the outer base variables of the optimal solution.
4. Generate the constraint that exclude the current optimal solution from your domain:
   $$ \sum_{i\in B} x_i \geq 1$$
5. Add the new constraint to $(P)$
6. Repeat the steps 3,4 and 5 until $(P)$ become empty. Terminate

Each solution you get is the minimal possible in the current domain, so you w'll get your subsets in the wanting order.

By doing that, I'm assuming that we have only positive numbers, if you have negative numbers (and evantually the number zero) you must omit the step one and the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \geq 1$ from $(P)$.

Comment: Can you prove that this runs in polynomial time, as required by the OP?

Comment: It's certainly not going to be amortised $O(1)$ per subset.

Comment: We must choose a subset among others, it is a combinatoric problem which is NP-complete, the proposed method in the general case at the first step is $O(\sqrt n)$, by adding the constraint at step 4, it will be $O(2^n)$ in the general case, but practically, it will be really speed up because we begin from the optimal solution. The inconvenient here is the program must use the Branch and Bound procedure to resolve it.